# Creating a python nested dictionaries from excel multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dictionary, xlrd

I have a excel worksheet as shown in figure [image: here]

It has 3 classes `C1,C2 and C3` where `C1` is the main class and here its only one as `Cars` but it could be multiple. `C2` is the category of `C1` and `C3` is the sub-category of `C1`. Is there any way I can convert this data into some good readable format something like `nested dictionaries` so I iterate over these classes using `for` loop? I have tried to convert it using:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
auto_cars=[]
def parse_xlsx():
    workbook = open_workbook('C:/Users/Downloads/TAXONOMY.xlsx')
    sheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    active_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheets[1])
    num_rows = active_sheet.nrows
    num_cols = active_sheet.ncols
    header = [active_sheet.cell_value(0, cell).lower() for cell in range(num_cols)]
    for row_idx in range(1, num_rows):
        row_cell = [active_sheet.cell_value(row_idx, col_idx) for col_idx in range(num_cols)]
        yield dict(zip(header, row_cell))

for row in parse_xlsx():   
    auto_cars.append(row)
```

Which gives confusing output as:

```
[{'c1': 'Cars ', 'c2': 'Class', 'c3': 'muv'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'hatchback'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'suv'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'sedan'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'coupe'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'convertible'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': 'Fuel Type', 'c3': 'electric'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'diesel'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'cng'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'petrol'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'lpg'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'hybrid'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': 'Brand', 'c3': 'ashok leyland'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'audi'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'bmw'},
 {'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': 'bentley'}
 ..................................
 .................................
```

Comment: What output would you prefer?  One option would be to cache your "c1" and "c2" values and copy them into subsequent rows if they aren't fully populated.

Comment: @BenJones All I want to map keywords of Class C3 with another list elements. So I need to convert it into some readable format so that I can iterate it later on.

Comment: So something like `fuelTypes = {'electric', 'diesel', 'cng' ...}`?  Note that `fuelTypes` would be a `set` not a `dict` here.

Comment: Or do you want to be able to recognize that 'electric' is a Fuel Type?  In that case, perhaps a `dict` of the following form: `keywords = {'electric': 'Fuel Type', 'audi': 'Brand' ...}`

Comment: Yeah, lets say I have list L1=['audi','bmw','electric']. All I want to map these list elements with Class C3 and specify something like for 'audi' should be Cars:brand:audi, 'bmw' should also be Cars:brand:bmw and 'electric' should be Cars:fuel type:electric? This is something Im looking for